# Нужна помощь с php кодом в базе данных SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

Задача такая есть база данных SQL для которой нужно написать php код который будит ***"определять товар, количество которого больше всего на складе, и выводить все сведения о нем"***.
Так же подойдёт обычный HTML код на языке php.
На скриншоте представлен пример HTML кода на языке php.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</HEAD>

<body>
  <?php
// определим начальные данные
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'sportwkola';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_table_to_show = 'group';

// соеденяемся с сервером базы данных
$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
or die("Could not connet: " . mysql_error());

// подключаемся к базе данных
mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());

// выбираем все значения из таблицы "student"
$sql="select * from `" . $db_table_to_show. "`";
$qr_result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

// выводим на страницу сайта заголовки HTML-таблицы
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>ID</th>';
echo '<th>Name</th>';
echo '<th>Size</th>';
echo '<th><a href="hall.php">Hall</a></a></th>';
echo '<th><a href="lessons.php">Lessons</a></a></th>';
echo '<th><a href="inventar.php">Inventory</a></a></th>';
echo '<th><a href="people.php">Trener</a></a></th>';
echo '<th><a href="people.php">Starosta</a></a></th>';
echo '<th><a href="people.php">Zam.Starosty</a></a></th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

// выводим в HTML-таблицу все данные клиентов из таблицы MySQL
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $data['id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['Name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['Size'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['Hall'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['Lessons'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['Inventory'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['Trener'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['Starosta'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: Скриншот взят с другого задания.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Пример html кода на языке php??))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Просто подставь свою переменную в которой будет значение из базы данных, которое нужно определить как максимальное. И все будет бенч :)

```
// а вот и цикл 
    for ($i = 1; $i < $cnt; $i++) { 
    if ($arr[$i] > $max) { 
    $index_max = $i; 
    $max = $arr[$i]; 
    } else 
    if ($arr[$i] < $min) { 
    $index_min = $i; 
    $min = $arr[$i]; 
    } 
    } 
    echo "Максимальное число \$arr[$index_max] = $max<br>"; 
    echo "Минимальное число \$arr[$index_min] = $min<br>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Сделай цикл проверки кол. товара.
Если попадается самое большое кол.то просто достаешь его из базы данных и вставляем на свою страницу в html, куда тебе там уже нужно ( в хедер,футер,контент и т.д)

Comment: Пожалуйста, если не трудно напишите сам цикл, я не очень понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: вы код нормально вставьте текстом, или все его перепечатывать должны ?

Comment: Сейчас исправлю.